# Soap xml to json for vue-quasar

Tags: json, xml, vue.js, soap

i have a soap response with this format

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="somelink">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:queryDataResponse xmlns:ns1="somelink">
         <WindowTabData NumRows="3" TotalRows="3" StartRow="0" xmlns="somelink">
            <DataSet>
               <DataRow>
                  <field column="Value">
                     <val>JoeBlock</val>
                  </field>
                  <field column="Name">
                     <val>Joe Block</val>
                  </field>
               </DataRow>
               <DataRow>
                  <field column="Value">
                     <val>GardenUser</val>
                  </field>
                  <field column="Name">
                     <val>GardenUser BP</val>
                  </field>
               </DataRow>
               <DataRow>
                  <field column="Value">
                     <val>SeedFarm</val>
                  </field>
                  <field column="Name">
                     <val>Seed Farm Inc.</val>
                  </field>
               </DataRow>
            </DataSet>
            <RowCount>3</RowCount>
            <Success>true</Success>
         </WindowTabData>
      </ns1:queryDataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and i need to parse it into json with something like

```
[
{"value": "JoeBlock", "Name":"Joe Block"},
{"Value": "GardenUser", "Name": "GardenUser BP"},
{"Value": "SeedFarm", "Name": "Seed Farm Inc."},
...

]
```

anyone can give me an example to parse it?

i tried using domparser like

```
let parser = new DOMParser()
let doc = parser.parseFromString(xmls, 'application/xml')
doc.querySelectorAll('DataRow').forEach(cap => {
console.log('parser', cap.textContent)
})
```

but all i got was

```
["JoeBlockJoe Block", "GardenUserGardenUser BP", "SeedFarmSeed Farm Inc."]
```

please help how to extract field column as key and separate the value

Answer (score 0):

this is what i ended up doing

```
 xmlparser(xmls) {
  let convert = require('xml-js')
  let parser = new DOMParser()
  let doc = parser.parseFromString(xmls, 'application/xml')
  let x = doc.getElementsByTagName('DataSet')
  let out = convert.xml2json(x[0].outerHTML, {
    compact: true,
    spaces: 4
  })
  let outp = JSON.parse(out)
  this.CreateJson(outp.DataSet.DataRow)

},
CreateJson(data) {
  let json = []

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let array = {}
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i].field.length; j++) {
      array[data[i].field[j]._attributes.column] =
        data[i].field[j].val._text
    }
    json[i] = array
  }
  console.log('json created : ', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4))
}
```

not that elegant solution yeah, so im open to suggestion to make it more elegant